# Run a PowerShell Script that Monitors a file that's lock but once unlocked runs a command

Tags: powershell

I have a text file that is written to by a CNC Controller, the file is locked until a certain command in executed on the CNC Controller, I want to have a PowerShell Script running that keeps checking this file and once it is no longer locked, PowerSheel opens up a certain Webpage on our Intranet that processes the file and stores that data in an SQL database.

I've seen some scripts to check if a file is locked and seen some that constantly monitors a file for if its Changed, i need a mix of both

P.S. i'm a complete novice on PowerShell!!!

This is the Script I want to use but want it not to look for CHANGED events but once the file $OUT$.DAT is no longer locked by nother process

```
### SET FOLDER TO WATCH + FILES TO WATCH + SUBFOLDERS YES/NO
$watcher = New-Object System.IO.FileSystemWatcher
$watcher.Path = "c:\ftpserver"
$watcher.Filter = "*.dat"
$watcher.IncludeSubdirectories = $true
$watcher.EnableRaisingEvents = $true  

### DEFINE ACTIONS AFTER AN EVENT IS DETECTED
$action = { $path = $Event.SourceEventArgs.FullPath
            $changeType = $Event.SourceEventArgs.ChangeType
            $logline = "$(Get-Date), $changeType, $path"
            Add-content "c:\ftpserver\log.txt" -value $logline
          }    
### DECIDE WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED 
Register-ObjectEvent $watcher "Changed" -Action $action
while ($true) {sleep 5}
```

Comment: This is the Script I'd like to use...

Comment: Have a look at this: https://benohead.com/powershell-check-whether-file-locked/

Comment: That's what I'm after check if file is locked but how do I add that into the WHICH EVENTS SHOULD BE WATCHED section? Total novice at PowerShell

Answer (score 1):

You can modify that code and add it to a function i.e. :

```
function checkLock {
    Param(
        [parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
        $filename
    )
    $file = gi (Resolve-Path $filename) -Force
    if ($file -is [IO.FileInfo]) {
        trap {
            return $true
            continue
        }
        $stream = New-Object system.IO.StreamReader $file
        if ($stream) {$stream.Close()}
    }
    return $false
}
```

You can then just chuck the function call into an if statement or a loop like so:

```
if ((checkLock $filename) -eq $true) {
    Write-Host "file locked"
    continue
}
else {
    Write-Host "file not locked"
    << code you want to run on unlocked file >>
}
```

Timed loop:

```
While ($True) {
    if ((checkLock $filename) -eq $true) {
        Write-Host "file locked"
        continue
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "file not locked"
        << code you want to run on unlocked file >>
    }

    start-sleep -seconds 10

}
```

This will run continually until canceled. If you want it to run for a set amount of time use:

```
$timeout = new-timespan -Minutes 1
$sw = [diagnostics.stopwatch]::StartNew()
While ($sw.elapsed -lt $timeout) {
    if ((checkLock $filename) -eq $true) {
        Write-Host "file locked"
        continue
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "file not locked"
        << code you want to run on unlocked file >>
    }

    start-sleep -seconds 10

}
```

Comment: Great thanks for this, how do i get this to keep looping or checking the file every 10 seconds for example? Then when it finds the file unlocked to run up a webpage but change its checking to say 30 seconds while the webpage code runs then go back to checking for the locked file every 10 seconds, also when the webpage runs the file will get deleted, so want to check for that error, hope that makes sense

Comment: Check my edit, the second part of your question is separate and not relevant to the initial question. I would also suggest you don't take that approach but rather wait for your code to finish before you continue the loop. An easy way to do this would be to use PowerShell jobs and a loop to check the job status, but that is just speculation if i don't know the actual code you are using.

Comment: Never seen `trap` before now. Good to know about